# Time Issue while I am Using Yii Frame work & maria db on Linux Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: php, yii2, mariadb, yii2-basic-app, mariasql

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYkHM.png)i just try to do signup form in Yii framework with MariaDB on Linux Ubuntu

when i try to create user i got this Message ::

```
enter code here
SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime value: '1532870185' for column 'created_at' at row 1
The SQL being executed was: INSERT INTO `user` (`username`, `email`, `password_hash`, `auth_key`, `status`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('aha', 'aha@ccc.cc', '$2y$13$vRBQsfnP/xpy3DBQz7XqPONO8gmViygRVqJNMuJ0cN9oDW.erj//.', 'wwNyKbSpc4drIUz53u6HRXx6XYKWrLEV', 10, '1532870185', '1532870185')

Error Info: Array
(
    [0] => 22007
    [1] => 1292
    [2] => Incorrect datetime value: '1532870185' for column 'created_at' at row 1
)

↵
Caused by: PDOException
SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime value: '1532870185' for column 'created_at' at row 1
```

i do some research , it's all about time but i didn't understand what should i do

I try to remove NO_ZERO_DATE , Nothing happen
I try to configure Ubuntu Time

but still the Same issue ?

could any one help please

Comment: You try to insert timestamp into datetime database field. You have 2 options either change created_at and updated_at database column type to timestamp or you have to convert the timestamp values to date time.

Answer (score 0):

It's about your table definition.

**Datetime format** is : `2012-04-19 13:08:22`, not `1532870185` (from your exception, its `timestamp`). You have to change `datetime` format to `timestamp` or change format of your date to `datetime` before inserting it to DB.

Comment: i already do it ,when i do the insert from phpmyadmin it goes well
but if i try to do it from the app it self , i face the issue again 
even i change the datetime in my app ??!!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
INSERT ... , '1532870185', ...
```

do

```
INSERT ... , FROM_UNIXTIME('1532870185'), ...
```

(The quotes are optional in this context.)

As a test:

```
mysql> select FROM_UNIXTIME('1532870185'),
              FROM_UNIXTIME(1532870185);
+-----------------------------+---------------------------+
| FROM_UNIXTIME('1532870185') | FROM_UNIXTIME(1532870185) |
+-----------------------------+---------------------------+
| 2018-07-29 06:16:25.000000  | 2018-07-29 06:16:25       |
+-----------------------------+---------------------------+
```

(The fractions of a second should be harmless.)

Comment: i didn't try this up to know but what if i am working with a team and they have a windows os also they are working on xampp !?

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem and could solve it. You should remove or comment this lines in User model:

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        TimestampBehavior::className()
    ];
}
```